# Список из кортежа и словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x

Собрать результаты в структуру вида: [(t, T), {«вещество1»: Tr1, …,«вещество3»: Tr3}]. Вычисления проводить в функциях.

Вопрос - как мне собрать такой список из кортежа и 3 словарей?
У меня путаница возникла из-за того, что у меня есть 3 переменные t, по переменной T идет цикл for с некоторым шагом, а значение Tr высчитывается в этом же цикле. И даны 3 вещества, поэтому и словарей 3.

Объясню, как я это вижу. Если сначала идти по циклу с T. (привел пример типо 1 и 2 итерации)

```
[(t1, T0), {"вещество1": Tr10, "вещество2": Tr20, "вещество1": Tr30,}]
[(t1, T1), {"вещество1": Tr11, "вещество2": Tr21, "вещество1": Tr31,}]
```

Этот код только считает нужные значения для Tr всех 3х случаев (вариантов значения t).

```
Tc1=132.9
Tc2=304.2
Tc3=190.6
print(list(map(lambda T: T/Tc1, range(100,200,5))))
print(list(map(lambda T: T/Tc2, range(100,200,5))))
print(list(map(lambda T: T/Tc3, range(100,200,5))))
```

Вроде бы преобразовал списки в словари, но при попытке собрать словари в в один список что-то не получилось (пробовал через ** и |). Продолжение идеи:

```
Tc1=132.9
Tc2=304.2
Tc3=190.6
l1=list(map(lambda T: T/Tc1, range(100,200,5)))
l2=list(map(lambda T: T/Tc2, range(100,200,5)))
l3=list(map(lambda T: T/Tc3, range(100,200,5)))
d1=dict.fromkeys(l1, "Вещество1")
d2=dict.fromkeys(l2, "Вещество2")
d3=dict.fromkeys(l3, "Вещество3")
print(d1)
print(d2)
print(d3)
result = d1 | d2 | d3
print("\n",result)
```

Comment: Предоставьте ваш код

Comment: Кода нет, потому что я не могу разобраться с порядком действий

Comment: Предоставьте ваш код какой есть, попробуем разобратся, что не так в вашем коде.

Comment: Добавил. В задании разрешено использовать map и zip

Comment: Напишите пример входных данных. Т.к. суть задания - просто скомпоновать данные, то алгоритм принципиально зависит от структуры исходных данных. Без их примера мы не можем сказать ничего конкретного.

Comment: T, t, имя вещества - пример входных данных. Больше ничего нет

Comment: так что на выходе должно получится? {"Вещество1": 0.7524454477050414, "Вещество2: 0.3287310979618672", "Вещество3": 0.7524454477050414)?

Comment: Как вторая часть выходной структуры - да, Как написал Сергей. Но первый элемент выходной структуры должен быть кортежем, состоящим из t и T. Причем, повторюсь, t имеет 3 фиксированных значения, T - цикл for с некоторым шагом.